# Spring Boot upgrade results in unresolvable circular reference

Tags: spring-boot

I upgraded my SpringBoot 1.3.5 to 1.5.2 RELEASE and am suddenly getting an error when my beans are being wired.  I am not doing constructor injection anywhere, so the circular reference makes no sense.

Here is my main class:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {
  ...
}
```

I have many @Configuration classes in my /src/java/../configuration/ such as

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // default strength = 10
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
...
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan()
public class MyApplicationConfiguration {
@Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer servletContainerCustomizer() {
        return new SessionTimeoutEmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer();
    }
...
}
```

I also have a CustomUserDetailsService that does use the passwordEncoder, but its never been a problem prior:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordResetTokenRepository passwordTokenRepository;
...
}
```

And then I am using Spock for my IntegrationTests by extending

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
public class BaseSpecification extends Specification {

def setup() {
    RestAssured.port = serverPort;
}

@Value('${local.server.port}')
private int serverPort;
}
```

So all this worked with Spring-Boot 1.3.5 but now that I upgraded I get the following when I build or run tests:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is
>   currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
>   ... Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is
>   currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

**UPDATE**
Based upon Andy comment, I moved some dependencies around and think I have it fixed.

1. Removed this from WebSecurityConfig and put them in MyApplicationConfiguration:

   @Autowired
   private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

   @Autowired
   public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {       auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return;
   }

   @Bean
   public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
       // default strength = 10
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
   }

While I do not have any constructor injection, it would seem the new Spring Security does it DI differently.  I cannot confirm it, but this is no longer an issue.

Comment: It looks like there's a cycle created by your `WebSecurityConfig`. Can you share your `CustomUserDetailsService`? It would appear to depend on the `PasswordEncoder` bean that's created by `WebSecurityConfig` while also being a dependency of `WebSecurityConfig`.

Comment: Andy, I do have a dependency there as you mentioned.  However, this has never caused an issue in two years, so why would the upgrade impact that?

Comment: A cycle like that often works more by luck than design. It's a different version of Spring Security in Spring Boot 1.3 and 1.5 which may have caused your luck to run out

Comment: So if I am not using constructor injection, how can I get around that dependency issue?  I upgraded my spring-security to 4.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT but that isn't going to address this issue I think.

Comment: I think I found the problem thanks to your initial comment. I updated the original post with my work, and if you could make your comment an answer I accept it.